# Typescript typeguards for generics not enforced

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

```
interface Foo {
    bar() : Promise<string>;
}

class MyFoo implements Foo {
    bar() : string {
        return "";
    }
}

class MyFoo2 implements Foo {
    bar() : Promise<number> {
        return new Promise<number>(null);
    }
}
```

Shouldn't each of the two implementations above cause an error?

- MyFoo does get an error, because it returns string and not Promise
- MyFoo2 returns a promise, but of the wrong type, and gets no error -- **why?**

What I can tell is that TypeScript seems to check the members of the return type and not the declared type. But is there a way to declare this interface in a way that requires the implementations to return the correct type?

**edit:** It seems that because the es6 interface `Promise` is defined with members like `then() : Promise<T>`, but nothing like `foo(): T`, the type checking doesn't work. If I simulate this with my custom generic interface, it will properly error if the interface contains a member of type `T`, but not of a generic of type `T`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the current stable version of TypeScript.

Sources:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12023
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10524
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10785

It has already been fixed and will be included in a future version (2.1).

I tried it myself too:

```
D:\Practice\TypeScript\ts-test>npm install -g typescript
C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── typescript@2.0.10


D:\Practice\TypeScript\ts-test>C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd --version
Version 2.0.10

D:\Practice\TypeScript\ts-test>C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd --target ES6 app.ts

D:\Practice\TypeScript\ts-test>npm install -g typescript@next
C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── typescript@2.2.0-dev.20161122



D:\Practice\TypeScript\ts-test>C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd --version
Version 2.2.0-dev.20161122

D:\Practice\TypeScript\ts-test>C:\Users\dezsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.cmd --target ES6 app.ts
app.ts(5,7): error TS2420: Class 'MyFoo2' incorrectly implements interface 'Foo'.
  Types of property 'bar' are incompatible.
    Type '() => Promise<string>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<number>'.
      Type 'Promise<string>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<number>'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Here you can see that trying with version 2.0.10 doesn't give me an error, while the latest 2.2.0-dev.20161122 correctly reports `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'`.

Comment: Oh, beautiful. Thanks for finding that!

Comment: Oddly enough i'm still able to compile with only the error regarding string vs "Promise<string>", are you using the same exact sample I had? Could it be I have other dependencies that are incorrect?
I have typescript@2.2.0-dev.20161122 and TSC 2.0.10. Are there potentially other dependencies that impact the lib used?